# Emacs in windows, gpg error

Tags: windows, emacs, elisp, gnupg

I am using emacs on windows. Whenever I look to encrypt file contents using epa-encrypt-file in gives the following error:

```
Searching for program: Permission denied, gpg
```

How do I correct this?

**EDIT**

I installed gpg at the same place as the .emacs and added this to .emacs:

```
(when (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
  (setq exec-path
'(
"e:/GnuPG/"
)
 ))
```

Now the shown error is:

```
peculiar error: "Can't decrypt", "Exit"
```

Comment: Do you have gpg installed on windows? If so, make sure it's in your exec-path.

Comment: Please look at the edit.

Comment: I've been digging through the epg elisp source and can't seem to find an answer, I apologize, I dont' have a Windows machine to be of further help.

Answer (score 0):

(setq explicit-shell-file-name
      "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash.exe")
(setq shell-file-name explicit-shell-file-name)
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin")

see 
[Windows, Emacs, Git Bash, and shell-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676750/windows-emacs-git-bash-and-shell-command)